# How to show username from User model to the index view of Quote controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations, erb

When I create a quote it asks for the quote body, author and user id, user and quotes are associated but I want to show the username of the user with the user ID that someone puts when a quote is create. So if a user has the username "shanks" and his ID is 4 and when user creates a quote and in the text field of user_id he enters 4... I want in the index view of Quotes controller to show the username of the user with that id.

```
def index
    @quote = Quote.new
    @quotes = Quote.order(created_at: :desc).all
    @user = User.new
end
```

view:

```
<!-- form to add a Quote -->
<div class="create-quote">
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
<%= f.label :quotetext %><br>
<%= f.text_field :quotetext %><br>

<%= f.label :author %><br>
<%= f.text_field :author %><br>

<%= f.label :user_id %><br>
<%= f.text_field :user_id %><br>
<%= f.submit "Add quote" %>
<% end %>
</div>
<!-- All quotes here -->
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        <%= quote.quotetext %>
    </p>
    <footer>
        <cite> 
            <%= quote.author %><br>
        </cite>
        <p>Posted by: <%= @user.username %> </p> <!-- this -->
    <%= link_to "Delete quote", quote_path(quote), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this beautiful quote?"}     %>
    </footer>
</blockquote>
<%= quote.like %></br>
<% end %>
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :quotes
validates :username ,presence: true
validates :password ,presence: true
end
```

quote model:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :quotetext, presence: true,
    length: { minimum: 5}
validates :author, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your quote is assosiated with user so when you do this it will give you user object

```
    quote.user
```

Now when you do `quote.user.username`, it will give user name for the user which is assosiated with the quote.

Use this

```
    <p>Posted by: <%= quote.user.try(:username) %> </p>
```

Comment: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Comment: this means that your user is not present for the quote. can you try to fetch the user for that quote using `quote.user` in rails console or even in the index page

Comment: That error occurs only when I enter a user_id of a user that doesnt exist when I create a quote..So if there is no user with ID 5 and I enter 5 to user_Id when I create the quote that error happens..But its working as long as I enter the ID of a user that exist...Thank you

Comment: im updating the answer to handle this error as well. that will help you if user does not exists still it wont crash

Comment: @kushtrimh Why would you want to create a quote from a user that doesn't exist?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't want that to happen, I still dont know how to make an error appear on the screen to tell that you cant make a quote with an ID of a user that doesnt exist

Comment: @kushtrimh it should not be an input field for the user to enter his id.if user is logged in,  user should automatically be associated to it at run time. if not logged in rather ask for email and create user too. or you should add email field as input, search for the user with email and associate that

Comment: @Athar do you know how I can make it...so instead of asking for user id, to ask for the users username? and also im kind of new to rails and I still haven't got to the authentication stuff. This app I have is simple

Comment: okay im assuming username exists in user table and is unique per user. now do this.. give the username field in place of user_id, change  `f.text_field` to `text_field_tag` so that it wont be associated to quote params, and in controller create action. before creating the quote add this line. `@user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first_or_create` now after initializing the quote in create before saving. add this `@quote.user = @user` and then `@quote.save`

Comment: you've helped me a lot with this app...thanks a lot @Athar

Comment: hope things will be easy for you now. and my pleasure.:)